# How can I pass an env variable to Next.JS app running inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I am trying to pass the api URL as an env variable to a Next.JS app running inside a Docker container

[Next.JS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) states that: "Next.js has built-in support for loading environment variables from .env.local into process.env." and "In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_."

So I created an env file called ".env.local" in the root folder of the project (same folder as the docker-compose.yaml file) with the content:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:80
```

I updated the docker-compose.yaml file like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  client:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env.local
```

However I am unable to read the client env file in the code.

I am trying to retrieve it like Next.JS documentation suggests, I guess:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/v1/`,
});
```

I also tried:

```
const serverUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL;

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${serverUrl}/api/v1/`,
});
```

It returns undefined

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, you need to use a variable to prevent nextjs from inlining the environment variable at build time. See the last example in this section: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: @HansKilian I think I tried to do what you said, I updated the question with an example, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

By default, environment variables are only available on the server. To access them on your client components, you need to expose them in your `next.config.js` file.

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...other properties,
  env: {
    PUBLIC_SERVER_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Now in your client components, you can directly access them with `process.env.PUBLIC_SERVER_URL`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately env variables cannot be injected at runtime since the code of next.js is built into static code. The only way to solve this problem is to pass the needed variable at build time if you want to used docker.

Take a look to this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14030) to understand it

Comment: Man I hate nextJS for this reason (as a devops)

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can delay those values until runtime.  Somewhere in your NextJS app you probably have a `<Head>` component, so within there you can load late-bound values at runtime:

```
export default function TopOfApp() {
    // ... etc.
    return (
        <Head>
            // etc.
            <script src="./settings.js"></script>
        </Head>
    );
}
```

And on your deployment have the settings.js script file like

```
window.myAppRuntimeSettings = {
    colorOfSky: 'blue';
};
```

As long as you don't defer the script's loading then your app will have `myAppRuntimeSettings.colorOfSky` available immediately.