# Using NextJs with Docker, how to solve environment variables

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm trying to deploy a NextJs application using Docker and k8s.
But using environment variables is unbelievable hard... I can't believe that it is this hard. ***Build once deploy anywhere*** principle is so common that this should really not be an issue, but here we are.

```
'Dockerfile'

ARG CUSTOM_PATH
ENV CUSTOM_PATH=${CUSTOM_PATH}
```

Then using it in the config for example:

```
'next.config'

const nextConfig = {
    output: 'standalone',
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/SomePage',
                destination: `${process.env.CUSTOM_PATH}/AnotherPage`,
                permanent: false,
            },
```

But ofc the CUSTOM_PATH is undefined... and the build fails.

Same when using AuthJS and [NEXTAUTH_URL](https://authjs.dev/getting-started/providers/oauth-tutorial#4-deploying-to-production).

Is the only solution to this to have different Docker Files per environment..

How have you solved this issue with having Docker, k8s, NextJS and environment variables.

Comment: try rename the config from `CUSTOM_PATH` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_CUSTOM_PATH`

Comment: The issue is not that I need the variables in the client. The issue is that the static files generated by Nextjs can't be used when deploying with docker and k8s. This thread explains it all: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22243

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76124346/how-can-i-pass-an-env-variable-to-next-js-app-running-inside-a-docker-container/77548032#77548032